# проблема с "привязкой" комментария к посту на сайте wp

Tags: php, wordpress, веб-программирование

на сайте wordpress стоит 2 блока. В левом отображаются 5 последних постов, в правом соответствующем анонс со ссылкой на страницу последнего комментария к соответствующему посту. И если с отображением последних постов проблем нет, то в лучшем случае (с использованием get_comments) по выбранному аргументу отображается один и тот же комментарий. Перепробовал разные варианты. В том числе comment_link comment_excerpt. Интересно то, что сами ссылки выводятся как задумано, а вот comment_excerpt() не отображается вообще никак. Где ковыряться? Посты отображаются с помощью get_posts.Может есть какой-нибудь аргумент для комментариев?/ Или в get_comments есть аргумент для привязки к посту?
Может кто плагин толковый соответствующий знает?

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'number' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'comment_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'status' => 'approve',
    'type' => 'comment', // только комментарии, без пингов и т.д...
);

if ($comments = get_comments($args)) {
    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
        $comm_link = get_comment_link($comment->comment_ID); // может быть тяжелый запрос ...
        $comm_short_txt = mb_substr(strip_tags($comment->comment_content), 0, 50) . '...';
        echo '<p>'. $comment->comment_author . ': <a rel="nofollow" href="'. $comm_link .'">' . $comm_short_txt . '</a></p>';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: добавьте код, которым выводите те блоки, с которыми у вас возникли проблемы

Comment: <?php $args = array(
                                'number'  => 1,
                                'orderby' => 'comment_date',
                                'order'   => 'DESC',
                                'status'  => 'approve',
                                'type'    => 'comment', // только комментарии, без пингов и т.д...
                                );

Comment: if( $comments = get_comments( $args ) ){
                                    foreach( $comments as $comment ){
                                    $comm_link = get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ); // может быть тяжелый запрос ...
                                    $comm_short_txt = mb_substr( strip_tags( $comment->comment_content ), 0, 50 ) .'...';

                                    echo '<p>'. $comment->comment_author .': <a rel="nofollow" href="'. $comm_link .'">'. $comm_short_txt .'</a></p>';  }
                                }
                                ?>

Comment: Так этот блок отображения коментов выглядит сейчас. Отображает в 5-ти местах один и тот же блок, отобраный по критерию 'comment_date'. Извиняюсь, но одним постом весь код выложить не получилось)))

Comment: вообще код нужно было добавить редактированием вопроса в тело записи :) но вроде бы у вас не указан `post_id` в передаваемых аргументах, поэтому видимо выводится один и тот же комментарий

Comment: Чтобы выводить последний комментарий из конкретной записи, вам нужно знать `post_id` этой записи и передавать его в массиве аргументов функции `get_comments()`

Comment: Я так понимаю аргумент post_id относится к get_comments? Вчера подставлял со значением '', поскольку по другим (и вообще wp 5.7.2  ненавидит отображать id постов, комментов. Для выявления их нужны отдельные танцы с бубном, да и посты то динамические, id постоянно другие)))) отображает информацию соответствующего поста 5 раз. Значит все таки надо как вы говорите редактировать вопрос "в теле записи". Очень буду признателен если уточните. В get_posts, setup_postdata, или вообще в single.php? Заранее спасибо за отнятое время!